# Button click closes activity

Tags: android, button, dialog, cancel-button

I have this piece of code in my app:

```
FloatingActionButton addBlogButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addBlog);
addBlogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final Dialog addBlog = new Dialog(BlogLister.this);
        addBlog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_addblog);
        addBlog.setTitle("Enter blog details : ");
        blogTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.blogTitle);
        blogURL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.blogURL);
        addIt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addIt);
        cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        addBlog.show();

        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addBlog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

However, when I click the `addBlogButton` in my app, it closes my activity instead of showing the dialog.

But when I remove:

```
cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        addBlog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

from my code, it works properly.

LOGCAT error:

```
03-13 19:17:40.048 27760-27760/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.innovapp.blogreadr, PID: 27760
                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                       at com.innovapp.blogreadr.BlogLister$1.onClick(BlogLister.java:37)
                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18440)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone tell me what the issue is and how to fix it?

**EDIT** what I mean by closes is that is works as how the android **BACK** button should, it takes me back to the previous activity

Comment: what do you mean it closes? post your logcat

Comment: what I mean by closes is that is works as how the android **BACK** button should, it takes me back to the previous activity

Comment: do you have any errors in the logcat??

Comment: logcat was flushing so I didnt see error.. error posted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
```

to:

```
cancelButton = (Button) addBlog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
```

You are calling `findViewById(int id)` on your activity's root view. It is returning null as you don't have any view with this id. To make it non-null, give it a reference and call [`Dialog.findViewById()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#findViewById(int))

Comment: Thanks! that fixed it, can you please explain why that had to be done?

Comment: Thanks again mate! Makes sense

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me what the issue is and how to fix it?

It is difficult to tell what is causing the behaviour from the provided code snippet so the answer is "probably no".

Update:
As @Malwinder mentioned you should look for the `Button` with ID of "cancel" in the `Dialog` and not in the "hosting" `Activity`.

Since your `Dialog` instance seems to have a clearly defined purpose(add a blog entry ?) I suggest you move that code into a separate class so it is easier to manage and debug. The `DialogFragment` class seems to be the best option for what you are trying to achieve. Have a read on the [API Guide for DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DialogFragment).